# Common numbers in sequences

Tags: recreational-mathematics, relations

Lets say we have a set $S$ of $N$ ($N\geq 3$) finite nonempty sequences of numbers, each of different length. Is the relation of "having some number or numbers in common" transitive on $S$? I have  no idea how to even start proving or disproving this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That relation is definitely not transitive. Think about $$ A = \{1,2,3\}, B = \{3,4,5,6\}, \textrm{ and } C = \{6,7,8,9,10\}.$$

Then $ArB$ and $BrC$, but $A$ is not related to $C$.

Comment: My brain is malfunctioning today, thanks!